# Python Statsmodels lib showing Power TTest

Tags: python, statsmodels

My target is to show the context of alpha_level, effect_size, sample size and power of such a `TTest` by using the library `statsmodels`.

As a beginning, I just want to show anything based in this created figure, but actually it doesn't matter what parameters I use, there will be no "curve" (or anything else) on this figure. Furthermore, the axis are always scaled horribly.

My code so far:

```
import statsmodels.stats.power as smp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

myTtest= smp.TTestPower()

figure = myTtest.plot_power(
  dep_var='nobs',
  nobs=100,
  effect_size=np.arange(0.2,0.5,0.8),
  alpha=0.05,
  ax=None,
  title='Title',
  plt_kwds=None
)

figure.show()
mpl.pause(1000)
```

Is there anybody, who can give a help to explain,

1. Why I can not see anything on this figure.
2. How to scale the axis?